# Angular 2 + Codeigniter - Linked CSS and JS not loading on WAMP?

Tags: codeigniter, angular

I followed the latest Angular 2.0 quickstart guide and everything is up to date. My application runs fine locally using lite-server, but all of my CSS and JS resources get 404 errors when I run it on WAMP. The index.html application page is the only thing that loads.

My folder structure is:

```
my-project/
   application/
       views/
          pages/
             app/
                assets/
                   css/
                      reset.css
                node-modules/
```

index.html head:

```
<head>

<base href="/">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/menu.css" />

<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
 <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>

</head>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Assets should be out side of application on the same level as index.php

Comment: @wolfgang1983 I'm using Angular2 so they have to be at the same level as application folder or lower or else Angular can't see them.